# Pytest not recognizing tests in some installed apps in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, pytest

I have an issue with pytest in which it executes tests in some installed apps but ignores some even after specifically trying to run tests on that said app it still won't recognize the app. The app that's not recognize currently is named `file_upload` when ever i run pytest with `pytest` it detects all tests in other apps (collected 52 items) excludes `file_upload` , when i also run `pytest -k file_upload` still says it collected 52 items and deselected 52 items, i named the test file with `test_endpoints.py` and in my pytest.ini i have the following configurations:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --ds=config.settings.test --reuse-db
python_files = tests.py test_*.py
```

i added file_storage to my installed apps and works perfectly when running migrations and the rest so it's probably a pytest issue but i can't figure exactly what.